# Why is Powershell truncating a Base64 string?

Tags: .net, powershell, base64

The following code is not correctly encoding long strings to Base64. What can I do to fix this?

> Input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
>
> Expected output:
>   VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZw==
>
> Actual output: VGhl

```
Param(
  [string]$stringToEncode
)

$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToEncode))

Write-Host $encoded
```

Comment: Use quotes, as your string contains spaces.

Comment: Just tried it from the command line: and it works. Therefore there is something else going on. I suspect the value of `$stringToEncode` is not what you think it is (try adding a `Write-Debug` and enabling debug output).

Comment: @Richard PetSerAl already pointed it out: the input most likely is passed on the command line as `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` (without quotes) not as a single string `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"` (with quotes). Thus only `The` is passed into `$stringToEncode` (`VGhl` == `The`).

Answer (score 1):

"VGhl" is the base64-encoded form of the word "The". Most likely you're calling the script like this:

```
C:\path\to\your.ps1 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Without quotes each word is parsed as a separate argument, so only the first word ends up in the parameter `$stringToEncode`. To avoid this put quotes around the sentence, so it's passed as a single argument:

```
C:\path\to\your.ps1 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```